# How to pass a function in unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing a customer imputer for this machine learning application. Just like any imputers, it has a `fit()` and `transform()` method. The first thing `transform()` does is to check if it has been "fitted" using `check_is_fitted`. Exception will be raised if it is not fitted.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
class GroupImputer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    
    def __init__(self, group_cols, impute_cols, metric):
        self.group_cols = group_cols
        self.impute_cols = impute_cols
        self.metric = metric
    
    def fit(self, df):
        impute_map = df.groupby(self.group_cols)[self.impute_cols].agg(self.metric).reset_index(drop=False)
        self.impute_map_ = impute_map
        return self 
 
    def transform(self, df):     
        check_is_fitted(self, 'impute_map_')
        for _, row in self.impute_map_.iterrows():
            idx = (df[self.group_cols] == row[self.group_cols]).all(axis=1)
            df.loc[idx, self.impute_cols] = df.loc[idx, self.impute_cols].fillna(row[self.impute_cols])
        
        return df.values
```

If I want to unit test `transform`. How do I skip `check_is_fitted`? Essentially it will just `pass` without checking `impute_map_` which will be provided in the test

Comment: The way `sklearn` itself handled this: always fit before transform, perhaps on synthetic data ([example](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/tests/test_random_projection.py#L270))

Comment: @Marat transform() can be called by itself without knowing if it is fitted before. Especially in the inference stage. I think it is necessary to test fit and transform separately

Comment: You can just mock out `check_is_fitted` in your test.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I ended up adding this line above my test method `@mock.patch('sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted', return_value=True)` and it seems to work. How do I mock a method without specifying the return_value though?

Comment: Just don't specify it, it's an optional argument.